# Why does dnf consider a package with a lower version number than the installed one an update?

Tags: fedora, upgrade, wine, dnf, version

On Fedora 36 I have installed package **wine-7.2-1.fc36.x86_64** from repo [fedora](https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch).

If I run "dnf upgrade" it wants to install version **7.12-1.fc36.x86_64** from repo [updates](https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f$releasever&arch=$basearch). Also the operation is labelled Upgrading, not Downgrading.

Why does dnf consider a package with a lower version number than the installed one an update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

7.12 is newer than 7.2; 12 is greater than 2.

See [the Wine release news](https://www.winehq.org/news/) for details. 7.2 was released on February 11 2022, 7.12 was released on July 1 2022.